# Click event Fire while scrolling the list view in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I created a list view dynamically using jQuery mobile but I am facing two issues on iPad:

- while scrolling the the list row click event is firing
- my header is being hidden while clicking a row. This issue caught while scrolling.

Here is my code.

```
var content = "<table>";
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    content += '<tr class="row" id="' + i + '"><td>' + 'result ' + i + '</td></tr>';
}
content += "</table>"
$('#here_table').append(content);


$(".row").click(function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/Q9QmF/

Comment: Try `tap` instead of `click`. Always use `.on`.

Comment: ok ..When i want to display pop up on button click .But my ui is part not seem good ..And header display first time of pop up ,here is code.http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/HesVd/

Comment: This is a different issue. http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/#option-positionTo

Comment: can you help me solve this issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/HesVd/7/

**Changes I made**

- Added an extra attribute to the `header`. This will make the header remain at the top even if you click in the list.

  ```
  data-tap-toggle="false"
  ```
- Formatted the listview so that the click happens only when you actually tap on it.